# Dataframe column value based on aggregation of several columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
A   B   C
1   4   0.1
2   3   0.5
4   1   0.7
5   2   0.2
7   5   0.6
```

I want to loop through the rows in the dataframe, and for each row perform on aggregation on columns A and B as:

```
Agg = row[A] / row[A] + row[B]

A   B   C     Agg
1   4   0.1   0.2
2   3   0.5   0.4
4   1   0.7   0.8
5   2   0.2   0.7
7   5   0.6   0.6
```

For all values of Agg > 0.6, get their corresponding column C values into a list, i.e. `0.7` and `0.2` in this case.

Last step is to get the minimum of the list i.e. `min(list) = 0.2` in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use vectorized operations: `add` for addition, `rdiv` for division (for A/(A+B)), `gt` for greater than comparison and `loc` for the filtering:

```py
out = df.loc[df['A'].add(df['B']).rdiv(df['A']).gt(0.6), 'C'].min()
```

We could also derive the same result using `query` much more concisely:

```py
out = df.query('A/(A+B)>0.6')['C'].min()
```

Output:

```py
0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating, you can try creating an `aggregate` function and apply it across all rows.

```
def aggregate(row):
  return row["A"] / (row["A"] + row["B"])

df["Agg"] = round(df.apply(aggregate, axis = 1), 1)
df[df["Agg"] > 0.6]["C"].min()
```

Output -

```
0.2
```